# How to prevent unknown publisher popup when running Inno Setup installer on another computer?

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, smartscreen

I've created an exe and compiled it with Inno Setup Compiler (v6.0.5). I've set `AppPublisher` to "MyCompany Ltd". But whenever I run it on a different computer to the one I created it on, a popup appears asking me if I want to run this program *"from an unknown publisher"*. Moreover, when I added it to Start-up on both computers, neither show the publisher on the Start-up tab of Task Manager.

So, how do I properly specify the publisher? And if I do, will this prevent the popup coming up? As I want it to run on Start-up, having a nice big popup every time I boot up my computer isn't really that great.

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "publisher" is not related to the `AppPublisher` directive.

The "publisher" is the subject of the code signing certificate used to sign the installer. You probably have not signed the installer. It's necessary these days. See [InnoSetup - Code Signing Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19160779/3478652).

Comment: Note that these days  you need EV certificate. See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/222140/43677